# How to Refresh page data API get data dynamically in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**I used the RefreshIndicator to pull to refresh the page data but it not working**

This is my code!! help me to over come the issue on refresh on data

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:apitest3/services/api_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'models/statusinfo.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}


class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
 
 late Future<Status> _status;
  
 

  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorkey =
  new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _status = API_Manager().getStatus();
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback(
            (_) => _refreshIndicatorkey.currentState?.show());
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    return Scaffold(
      
      body: SafeArea(
        child: RefreshIndicator(
          key: keyStatus,
          onRefresh: () => _status,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.blue])),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: FutureBuilder<Status>(
              future: _status,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                      itemCount: 1,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        var result = snapshot.data!.result.syncInfo;
                        return Flexible(
                          child: Card(
                            elevation: 20,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.indigo.shade900,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Latest Block Hash ",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          )),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      RaisedButton.icon(
                                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(
                                                text: result.latestBlockHash));
                                            key.currentState!
                                                .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                                                 backgroundColor:Colors.amberAccent,
                                                  content: new Text(
                                                "Copied to Latest Block Hash!!",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.red),
                                              ),
                                            ));
                                          },
                                          icon: Icon(
                                            Icons.copy,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            size: 15,
                                          ),
                                          label: Text(
                                            "${result.latestBlockHash}",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 7.1,
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            maxLines: 1,
                                          )),
                                         ),
                                       ),
                                     ),
                                   );
                                }
                               }
                               ),
                                ),
                               
                                Card(
                                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 20,
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            " ${result.latestBlockTime
                                                .toString()}",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 10,
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                } else
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                    //CupertinoActivityIndicator()
                  );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know what i made mistake on this code for refresh function
And all so i try to root navigation method but it pop more pages on the same page so once try to close the page it there several pages to close,
so,  try to help me on proper way to pull refresh on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the state after refreshing on `onRefresh` callback. Currently, you are just assigning it to a `Future` variable.

This is a simple way to do it.

```
RefreshIndicator(
   onRefresh: () { setState((){
         // Update your data here
       }); },
   child: ...
  )
```

Comment: Give me some examples for complete code or links to set 'setState' in a flutter.